# RREF of uneven matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this matrix:

> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
> 1 & 2 & 4
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find the RREF

**Question:** How does RREF work if $m \ne n $ [col =/= rows]

The algorithm is to get the top left to 1 then ignore the top row and leftmost column and the continue, but because this is uneven, I don't see how that works?

Comment: Subtract $2R_2$ from $R_1$. Then subtract $R_1$ from $R_2$.

Comment: Your description is pretty straight forward. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @user251257 , usually its in the form: $$\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0  \\ 
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$, I dont see how to get it here

Comment: @kalra I don't think you understand what RREF is. That's just identity matrix, and while that is in RREF, not all RREF has to be identity.

Comment: Recall what RREF is for the dummies. Let me guess : the first letters should be Row Reduction ? But the last ones ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Row Reduced Echelon Form

Comment: @user160738 Thnk you, I feel a little less dummy (I should have guessed...)

Answer (score 1):

1. Swap R1 and R2: $\quad\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\3&4&5\end{bmatrix}$,
2. Subtract 3 R1 from R2: $\quad\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\0&-2&-7\end{bmatrix}$,
3. Add R2 to R1: $\quad\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3\\0&-2&-7\end{bmatrix}$,
4. Divide R2 by $-2$: $\quad\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3\\0&1&\frac72\end{bmatrix}$.